# How to write this output in array foam, which remaining array - array postion output 0.0000

Tags: pygtk

import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(PyApp, self).__init__()

    self.set_title("Entry")
    self.set_size_request(300, 300)
    self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

    fixed = gtk.Fixed()

    self.label = gtk.Label("Entry")
    fixed.put(self.label, 40, 40)

    self.entry = gtk.Entry()
    fixed.put(self.entry, 80, 40)

    button1 = gtk.Button("OK")
    button1.connect('clicked', self.button_clicked)
    fixed.put(button1, 130, 90)


    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    self.add(fixed)
    self.show_all()

def button_clicked(self, widget):
    with open('entry.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(self.entry.get_text())
```

PyApp()
gtk.main()

I need the output to be like this:

> entry_text 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
>
> 0.0000     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
>
> 0.0000     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
>
> 0.0000     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000

All help is appreciated!

Comment: So you want the one value from the entry to be written in a file the way you specified?

Comment: yes bro can you able to help me..